# Compress movies on Android

Tags: java, android, video, compression

I have a game where users complete assignment by making a picture that will be send to the backend. Before sending this to the backend the image is resized to limit the amount of data that has to be send. This all works fine.

Now I want to extend this with movie clips. Movie clips are a lot bigger then picture. Especially if you don't compress them. The problem is that I have no clue how to do this.

So the main question is how can change my app that the user records a video and after it compress it to make the file smaller in size. Are there libraries around to do this? Or is there something in Android itself to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that works is to use ffmpeg to do the compression.

There are some well used ffmpeg libraries that will allow you include ffmpge via a wrapper and then use standard ffmpeg syntax to perform the compression within your app.

See this one which includes examples:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Note that video compression is power and battery intensive, and takes time so you may want to limit the clip size if you plan to have users use this functional regularly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!